# How to save and retrieve data from specific row in SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'am making an app where user can log in to his account, past something in `EditText`, then it will be displayed in `TextView`. My point is to save and then display each user's own text. Here what i got so far

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserManager.db";

    // User table name
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

    // User Table Columns names
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "userid";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "user_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_HOURS = "user_hours";

    // create table sql query
    private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_HOURS + " TEXT" + ")";

    // drop table sql query
    private String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER;
    SQLiteDatabase db;


    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        this.db = sqLiteDatabase;
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //Drop User Table if exist
        db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public void addUser(User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, user.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public boolean checkUser(String name, String password) {

        // array of columns to fetch
        String[] columns = {
                COLUMN_USER_ID
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        // selection criteria
        String selection = COLUMN_USER_NAME + " = ?" + " AND " + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " = ?";

        // selection arguments
        String[] selectionArgs = {name, password};

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, //Table to query
                columns,                    //columns to return
                selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
                selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                       //group the rows
                null,                       //filter by row groups
                null);                      //The sort order

        int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        if (cursorCount > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void updateData(UserData userData) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_HOURS, userData.getHours() );

        // updating row
        db.update(TABLE_USER, values, COLUMN_USER_HOURS + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(userData.getHours())});
        db.close();
    }
```

i want the user's EditText value to be stored and retrievied from column `COLUMN_USER_HOUR` sadly i have no idea how to set it up all together
 , im assuming that `COLUMN_USER_HOUR` should be identified for each user's id. Thanks for help ;)
Here's UserData

```
public class UserData {
    private String hours;

    public String getHours(){
        return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(String hours){
        this.hours = hours;}

}
```

Comment: Look into official Room library and save yourself the trouble of writing all that SQLiteOpenHelper code.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `upDateData` method to be as follows :-

```
public int updateData(long userid, UserData userData) {
    int rv;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_HOURS, userData.getHours() );

    // updating row
    rv = db.update(TABLE_USER, values, COLUMN_USER_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{Long.toString(userid)});
    db.close();
    return rv;
}
```

So you pass the **userid** as well as the data to be changed, the method will return the number of updates made (1 if it worked, 0 if nothing was updated).

---

#### Answer re :-

> I know that, but for now i only wanted to know how to save and
>   retrieve data for unique user ( when user log in to his account i want
>   to display in textview that what he stored in data by edittext ) i
>   know it sounds really weird, but im trying to understand how to
>   structure the data :)

A similar change, instead of returning a boolean return the userid (0 if failed) e.g. :-

```
public long checkUser(String name, String password) {
    long rv = 0;

    // array of columns to fetch
    String[] columns = {
            COLUMN_USER_ID
    };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    // selection criteria
    String selection = COLUMN_USER_NAME + " = ?" + " AND " + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " = ?";

    // selection arguments
    String[] selectionArgs = {name, password};

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, //Table to query
            columns,                    //columns to return
            selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
            selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                       //group the rows
            null,                       //filter by row groups
            null);                      //The sort order

    if (cursor.moveToFirst) {
        rv = Long.toString(cursor.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_ID);
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return rv;
}
```

And you could have a `getHours` method like:-

```
public String getHours(long id) {
    String rv = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWriteableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, 
        null,
        COLUMN_USER_ID = "+?",
        new String[]{Long.toString(id)},
        null,null,null
    );
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_HOURS));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return rv;
}
```

Your Activity could include something like :-

```
    DatabaseHelper dbhlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    long current_userid = dbhlpr.checkUser(
            username_EditText.getText().toString(),
            userpassword_EditText.gettext.toString());
    if (current_userid > 0) {
        hours_TextView.settext(dbhlpr.getHours(current_userid));
    } else {
        //.... handle invalid login attempt here.
    }
```

Comment: Well im a little bit confused, but i think im gonna handle this :), now im wondering how to retrieve that user data to his UserActivity `TextView`

Comment: Depending on the UserData class you could get the userid i.e. `userData.getId()` if the getter exists and is called that an it returns a long. You could if you know that username is unqiue use that e.g. `new String[]{userData.getUserName()});`, again if the getter exists.

Comment: for now my UserData looks like this in my question (i added it), and i know that username will be unique.

Comment: The problem with what you were trying is that you were basically saying update the row(s) where the hours is 10 (or whatever the value of hours is) and change them to 10 hours. So would never do anything of any use.

Comment: I know that, but for now i only wanted to know how to save and retrieve data for unique user ( when user log in to his account i want to display in textview that what he stored in data by edittext ) i know it sounds really weird, but im trying to understand how to structure the data :)